# Changing element in another ViewController

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS and have a very basic question. I've googled and can't find the answer.

I have a UILabel on one ViewController and view and would like to change the font color with:

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

but in another ViewController. Is that possible?

So myLabel is in the first ViewController and the button to change the color of myLabel is in the other ViewController.

So more information like yall asked:

My app is compiled of tons of buttons with simple commands. All the buttons are in the same area so I thought of putting some of them on a different view instead of just piling buttons on top of each other and calling .hidden = true; on them.

Comment: Roger Nolan has a good answer, but I also think it would be helpful for you to clarify what kind of relationship these view controllers have. Is one pushed or presented from the other (master/detail)? Is one contained by the other (parent/child)? Are they contained by the same container (siblings, like in a tab bar controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but it does not immediately sound like a good design. Without knowing more about your app...

If the color change is to reflect some change in your model you should effect the change through your model:

--(UIEvent)--> ViewController1 --(update)--> model --(observe)--> ViewController2 --(change color)-> textField.

If your app is not that complicated, you should at the very least implement a method on ViewController2 that is descriptive of the reason why the text field should change and send that message (call the method) from ViewController1.

You will also need to pass a reference to VC2 into VC1 - you either already have this because there is a VC1->VC2 parent child relationship or you will have to do it through a joint parent.